# How to do the same calculation for each row and keep the calculation in that row in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

In my spreadsheet, I want to calculate the total value from B1 to F1 and keep that value into G1. I want to calculate this for each row until the the last row. If user click a command button it will calculate the value and keep that value into G column

For Example:

```
Sl.   A     B    C   D   E   F  G
1.    5     2    1   3   0   1  12
2.    1     0    4   1   2   9  17
```

Here is my code which can calculate only 1st row:

```
Private Sub Sum_Click()
Dim ShowTotal As Integer
ShowTotal = Range("B1") + Range("F1")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1").Value = ShowTotal
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code currently adds B1 and F1 only. You probably want to use a FOR loop or two here, google excel vba for loop for more

Comment: I am new in VBA. Can you tell me the way of writing for loop for this?

Comment: google "excel vba for loop tutorial", literally you can just copy paste what i typed, it will be faster than me explaining

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Sum_Click()
    Dim LastRow as Long
    Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("G1:G" & LastRow).Formula = "=sum(B1:F1)"
End Sub
```

LastRow: will check the last used row in sheet

Range("G1:G" & LastRow).Formula = "=sum(B1:F1)" Will put the appropriate formula in all the required cells of G column.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Another Question, Can you tell me how can I subtract current date from B1? 
I have tried "=B1-Date"

But it didn't work.

Comment: You can use Now() instead of Date.

Comment: You can use function Format() to format your result.

Comment: I want to calculate year between two dates.

Comment: DateDiff("y", Now(), "1/7/1989")
didn't work this function